# Downloading multiple files at the same time having checkboxes

Tags: html

I have a HTML page which has the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

function validate(frm)
{
  var count = 2;
  var allChecked = false;
  for(i=1; i<=count; i++)
  {
    if( document.getElementById('track_'+i).checked == true)
    {
        allChecked = true;
        break;
      }
  }
    if(!allChecked)
    {
        alert("Please select atleast one track");
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="get" onSubmit="validate(this);">

<input type="checkbox" value="01 - Sun Beliya - Lata, SP Balasubramaniam @ Fmw11.com.mp3" id="track_1" name="track_1"><a href ="01 - Sun Beliya - Lata, SP Balasubramaniam @ Fmw11.com.mp3">01 - Sun Beliya - Lata, SP Balasubramaniam @ Fmw11.com.mp3  </a> <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="02 - Gabbar Singh Yeh Kah - Alka Yagnik, Amit Kumar @ Fmw11.com.mp3" id="track_2" name="track_2"><a href ="02 - Gabbar Singh Yeh Kah - Alka Yagnik, Amit Kumar @ Fmw11.com.mp3">02 - Gabbar Singh Yeh Kah - Alka Yagnik, Amit Kumar @ Fmw11.com.mp3  </a><br>
<input type="submit" value="Download" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to download both files at the same time i.e. when both checkboxes are selected then both files should be downloaded.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

function validate(frm)
{
  var SomeChecked = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++)
  {
      if(tracks[i].checked) 
      {
          SomeChecked = true;
          var url= tracks[i].value;    
          window.open(url,'Download');  
      }
  }
  if(!SomeChecked)
  {
      alert("Please select atleast one track");
  }
  return false;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" onSubmit="validate(this);">

<input type="checkbox" value="01 - Sun Beliya - Lata, SP Balasubramaniam @ Fmw11.com.mp3" id="track_1" name="tracks"><a href ="01 - Sun Beliya - Lata, SP Balasubramaniam @ Fmw11.com.mp3">01 - Sun Beliya - Lata, SP Balasubramaniam @ Fmw11.com.mp3  </a> <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="02 - Gabbar Singh Yeh Kah - Alka Yagnik, Amit Kumar @ Fmw11.com.mp3" id="track_2" name="tracks"><a href ="02 - Gabbar Singh Yeh Kah - Alka Yagnik, Amit Kumar @ Fmw11.com.mp3">02 - Gabbar Singh Yeh Kah - Alka Yagnik, Amit Kumar @ Fmw11.com.mp3  </a><br>
<input type="submit" value="Download" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you change the Checkboxs names to "**tracks**" they all should have the same name but diffrent ID.

And it the value of each checkbox place the download URL.

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt reply. I tried the exact code that you provided. The download did not initiate :(

Comment: @iamfunoo First of all the value isn't a URL now, and second make sure you copy it all including the HTML part.
change the value to a working URL, and if it still doesn't work
try pasting your code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and put it here.

I updated the code watch the form method is now 'post' VERY IMPORTENT.

Comment: I could not put the exact URL because it is confidential. Sorry about that. But this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Danpe above had pretty close to the right idea, but the second if statement should have the newer var name:

```
 if(!allChecked) {
     alert("Please select at least one track");
 }
```

Should be:

```
 if(!Checked) {
     alert("Please select at least one track");
 }
```

Comment: Yes lol i fixed it xD
Just forgot, and next time comment on my answer and dont post a new answer :)

Comment: Also, depending on how you want the user experience to be, you may consider doing a Zip file of the two tracks and then if all of them are checked, get that instead of opening two windows for the two different files.

Comment: @Danpe: yeah, sry about that.  I typed in what I already had open instead of thinking